# Portlet ActionRequest generation with Web Experience Factory 7.0.1

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, portlet, websphere-portal

I am having strange issues with ActionRequest generation for portlet. I use WebSphere portal link builder in my source portlet

It has an option of specifying whether the  URL it generates will be a action/render url.

**action**
Portlet action processing
**render**
Portlet render processing

Even though I specify "action" as url generation type it always generates a Render url.

In my target portlet i write below code

```
if (webAppAccess.getHttpServletRequest().
        getAttribute(Constants.PORTLET_REQUEST) instanceof ActionRequest) {

    System.out.println("Its an action request ");
} else if (webAppAccess.getHttpServletRequest().
        getAttribute(Constants.PORTLET_REQUEST) instanceof RenderRequest) {

    System.out.println("Its a Render request ");
}
```

Its always going to the else if block. I am not sure why.
Can any one suggest any ideas?
Thanks,
Arajit

Answer (score 0):

Arajit

- Where are you placing the above code?  (eg, in the page, in main, in an explicitly called action?).   If it's just in a method called on page render, then you would expect a render request.  It will only be an ActionRequest if it's an explicitly called action, not using AJAX for partial page rendering.
- What is the use case?  There may be an alternative to the Portal Link builder (eg, such as JSR286 events via the Cooperative Portlet builders).

You may find more experts on Web Experience Factory and questions/answers on the #WEF forum at:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/forum?id=11111111-0000-0000-0000-000000000889

I hope that info helps,
..Mike Burati 
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/pfwiki.nsf/
The postings on this site are my own and do not necessarily represent the positions, strategies, or opinions of IBM.